# Namespacing service objects in Rails 6 with Zeitwerk autoloader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

Rails 6 switched to Zeitwerk as the default autoloader. Zeitwerk will load all files in the /app folder, eliminating the need for namespacing. That means, a TestService service object in app/services/demo/test_service.rb can now be directly called e.g. `TestService.new().call`.

However, namespacing has been helpful to organize objects in more complex rails apps, e.g. [API::UsersController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675838/rails-6-convention-for-declaring-namespaced-classes-zeitwerk-autoloader), or for services we use Registration::CreateAccount, Registration::AddDemoData etc.

One solution [suggested by the rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#having-app-in-the-autoload-paths) is to remove the path from the autoloader path in application.rb, e.g. `config.autoload_paths -= Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/demo/"]`. However, that feels like a monkey patch for shoehorning an old way or organizing objects into the new rails way.

What is the correct way of namespacing objects or a rails 6 way of organizing it without just forcing rails into the old way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true to say that Zeitwerk eliminates 'the need for namespacing'. Zeitwerk does indeed autoload all the subdirectories of `app` (except `assets`, `javascripts`, and `views`). Any directories under `app` are loaded into the 'root' namespace. But, Zeitwerk also 'autovivifies' modules for any directories under those roots. So:

```rb
/models/foo.rb => Foo
/services/bar.rb => Bar
/services/registration/add_demo_data.rb => Registration::AddDemoData
```

If you are already used to loading constants from 'non-standard' directories (by adding to `config.autoload_paths`), there's usually not much change. There are a couple of cases that do require a bit of tweaking, though. The first is where you are migrating a project that just adds `app` itself to the autoload path. In classic (pre-Rails 6), this allows you to use `app/api/base.rb` to contain `API::Base`, whereas in Zeitwerk it would expect it to contain only `Base`. That's the case you mention above where the recommendation is to exclude that directory from the autoload path. Another alternative would be to simply add a wrapper directory like `app/api/api/base.rb`.

The second issue to note is how Zeitwerk infers constants from file names. From the Rails migration guide:

> `classic` mode infers file names from missing constant names
> (underscore), whereas zeitwerk mode infers constant names from file
> names (camelize). These helpers are not always inverse of each other,
> in particular if acronyms are involved. For instance, `"FOO".underscore`
> is `"foo"`, but `"foo".camelize` is `"Foo"`, not `"FOO"`.

So, `/api/api/base.rb` actually equates to `Api::Base` in Zeitwerk, not `API::Base`.

Zeitwerk includes a rake task to verify autoloading in a project:

```sh
% bin/rails zeitwerk:check
Hold on, I am eager loading the application.
expected file app/api/base.rb to define constant Base
```

Comment: Thank you so both for asking and answering this question. rmlockerd, you not only made my day, but whole month! :man-bowing:

Comment: I think `bin/rails Zeitwerk:check` should be `bin/rails zeitwerk:check`

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

As clarified in comments, you actually don't need to add anything to `autoload_paths`. It's default behaviour for Zeitwerk in Rails when your place your code under some subdirectory in `app`.

### Original answer:

I'm posting separate answer, but actually accepted answer has all the good information. Since my comment was bigger than allowed, I chose to add separate answer for those who are struggling with similar issue.

We have created "components" under app where we separate domain specific namespaces/packages. They co-exists with some "non-component" Rails parts, that are hard to move under components. With classic autoloader, we have added `#{config.root}/app` in our autoload_paths.

This setup fails for Zeitwerk and removing `"#{config.root}/app"` from autoload_paths didn't help. rmlockerd suggestion to move `app/api/` under `/app/api/api` moved me thinking in creating separate `'app/components'` and moving all components under this directory and add this path to `autoload_paths`. Zeitwerk likes this.

Comment: You do not need to add `app/components` to the autoload paths by hand, it is done automatically by Rails.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm kind of surprised that it actually works. I tried to find some documentation about it, but couldn't.

Comment: Sure, it is documented here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths

Comment: Oh. I was thinking there was something magical about `app/components` but it actually works with any name except few exceptions. Thanks for clarifying.